# How to access multiple passed user defined parameters in Powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

In my stored procedure I am passing multiple arguments like below code.

```sql
declare @sql as varchar(255) 
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -c "get-service |   
C:\SharedData\SIMSv1.0\Templates\OC\SIMS_Consolidation.ps1  
'+CONVERT(varchar(2),@taskType)+' '+CONVERT(varchar(2),@strVendorID)+' ' 
+CONVERT(varchar(20), @dteBatchDate) + '"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

and in my Scripts I am following approach to access passed arguments:

```powershell
$numOfArgs = $args.Length
for ($i=0; $i -le $numOfArgs; $i++)
{
    if($i-eq 0)
    {  
        $taskType= ($args[$i])   
    }
    elseif($i -eq 1)
    {
        $strVendorID=($args[$i])
    }
    else 
    {  
        $dteBatchDate= $dteBatchDate+''+ ($args[$i])    
    }   
}
```

Like this I am not able to access all the passed arguments.